# Start WAMP Server in order to start MySQL server

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I am working on web app development and for the data storage I am using MySQL server. Although I start the WAMP server before starting MySQL server, the question," why it is need", always arises in my mind. Can someone help me with proper answer for my question?

Answer (score 0):

Any website needs server to be published and saved to , so to be able to test your webpage without publishing it to online server and need to pay even if you are learning/Coding beside being online and allowed to entered by anyone 'unless you use firewall' , It's like making a local,free server for you to test and work your website , after you finish your website you can buy domain , host and publish your website to
Try entering url like 'localhost/index.php' without turning on any Apache server you will find error msg as 'This site can’t be reached' ,
So that is the role of wamp or any other app like xamp,etc

Answer (score 0):

WAMP server is in fact serveral services running underhood, by default they are started by starting WAMP application which takes care of this. Namely these:

```
wampapache64
wampmariadb64
wampmysqld64
```

If you want to skip wamp application and let them be started on startup you need to change settings in `Services` from `Manual` to `Automatic`